# clearing local storage when the browser is closed Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I create a react application that has authentification when the user is logged, its information is saved in the local storage but the problem is when I try to close the browser and open the user information remain in the local storage.
I tried a lot of solution here but the problem is when I click on the sign-in button the local storage get clear and that what I don't want because the user can never get to the application
is there a solution that the local storage gets clear only when closing the browser thanks.

Comment: How about using `sessionStorage`?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a perfect use case for [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) as the data will be deleted when the tab/window is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is designed to be somewhat persistent, even after the browser is closed. If you want to delete the data when the user exits their browser, perhaps it would be better to just store all the data you need in memory, using perhaps a react context provider that can provide it to the components which require it.